# C# .NET 4 Self-Contained Oracle Driver Deployment

Tags: c#, oracle, ldap

I want to write and deploy some software without the need to install Oracle drivers on the users' workstations, rather, I would like to copy everything needed to a network location, and for the users to launch from there.

I have successfully established an `OracleConnection` by deploying the following to the application's folder.  (I took these from instantclient-basiclite-nt-11.2.0.3.0 provided by Oracle )

```
oci.dll
ociw32.dll
orannzsbb11.dll 
oraocci11.dll
oraociicus11.dll
```

I have found this works with an LDAP Query to establish the `DataSource=` part of the connection string.  The code I use is as follows - I hope this is useful to someone.

`List<string> LDAPServers`
`string OracleInstance`

```
    private string GetOracleNetDescriptor()
    {
        string result = null;

        foreach (string ldapserver in LDAPServers)
        {  
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://{0}", ldapserver), null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);

                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("orclnetdescstring");
                ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                ds.Filter = String.Format("(CN={0})", OracleInstance);

                SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

                if (sr != null)
                {
                    result = Encoding.Default.GetString(sr.Properties["orclnetdescstring"][0] as byte[]);
                    break;
                }

            }
            catch 
            {
                result = null;
            } 
        }

        if (result == null) 
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed To Identify Oracle Instance '{0}' From LDAP", OracleInstance)); 
        else
            return result;
    }
```

So far so good, however ...

1. The solution is currently dependent on a reference to the deprecated `System.Data.OracleClient` which I really need/want to avoid
2. I would like to get access to some advanced features, such as Entity Framework.

Can the panel advise ?

I would also appreciate any comments on the ldap code above as this is all work-in-progress.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with the deprecated provider. I've made good expiriences with Devart dotConnect for Oracle:
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/
It is not free of charge (and I'm not related to this company nor would I benefit in any kind).
It works with ADO.Net's DataTable and DataSet. As some years passed since my last usage I don't know how well it integrates with EF.

Comment: It does say on the page you've linked that it's compatible with EF:  http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/entityframework.html

Comment: Thanks but third party solutions are not an option for me on this occasion.